# SP 2010 Client Object Model - Minimum permissions

Tags: sharepoint-2010

What are the minimimum (site collection) user permissions required to use the client object model?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum will be Read Permissions (or as part of the Visitors group) to connect to the site.

I'm not certain if a user that is not specified in the Site permissions can connect to an Anonymous Site, however.

Comment: Just to clarify, restricted read is the minimum (not read) and the client object model needs to authenicate unless the lockdown feature is disabled.